# Cordova geolocation in IOS not working

Tags: ios, cordova, ios7, geolocation

I am working in a project that uses Cordova geolocation plugin that will search for users around you. However, I cannot get the geolocation from the simulator, nor on the device. Before I use to get the coordinates but very unstable. After some code to fix the bug, I am now getting an error most of the time. I tried this for a week with no success.
Any input, or advice?

The JavaScript file:

```
/***********Geolocation GEOLOCATION*************/        


// Wait for device API libraries to load

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {

    var options = {maximumAge: 0, timeout: 15000, enableHighAccuracy:true};

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
}


// onSuccess Geolocation
//
var onSuccess = function(position) {
    document.getElementById('userLat').value = position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById('userLong').value = position.coords.longitude;

    document.getElementById('extraUserLat').value = position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById('extraUserLong').value = position.coords.longitude;
    //document.getElementById('extraUserTest').innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;


};

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('There Was An Error Getting Your Location. Please Check That You Have WiFi and Location Services Enabled. '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');


}
```

The XML file:

```
<js-module src="www/Coordinates.js" name="Coordinates">
        <clobbers target="Coordinates" />
    </js-module>

    <js-module src="www/PositionError.js" name="PositionError">
        <clobbers target="PositionError" />
    </js-module>

    <js-module src="www/Position.js" name="Position">
        <clobbers target="Position" />
    </js-module>

    <js-module src="www/geolocation.js" name="geolocation">
        <clobbers target="navigator.geolocation" />
    </js-module>

    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="Geolocation">
            <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation"/>
            <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation" />
        </feature>
    </config-file>
    <header-file src="ios/CDVLocation.h" />
    <source-file src="ios/CDVLocation.m" />
    <framework src="CoreLocation.framework" />

    <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
        <string></string>
    </config-file>
```

HTML:

Comment: Did you test in iOS 8?

Comment: Hi @NijilNair, Deployment target is 7.0.

Comment: OK.The device you tested is iOS7/8?? There is a bug for Geolocation Plugin in iOS 8. Add this to your config.xml and check if it works.

<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" overwrite="false">
            <array>
                <string>Allow GPS</string>
            </array>
        </gap:config-file>

Comment: Hi again @NijilNair I am running the simulator and getting the same error with both iOS 7 and 8. I added the code in XML you told me just in case we also run it on iOS8 later, but again, I get no geolocation with the simulator with 7 anyway.

Comment: Modify your config.xml as I said (for iOS 8) and test the app in real device.

Comment: @NijilNair am also getting the same error. i have added your code in platforms/ios/NavSustain/config.xml config file. But no luck. Did you find any fix.

Comment: @user3356128 Did you find any fix?

Comment: I am not using Xcode. Building using PhoneGap Build. By adding <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" overwrite="false"> <array> <string>Allow GPS</string> </array> </gap:config-file>
in config.xml did the trick for me.

Comment: Try `overwrite=true` for a more explicit result. In some cases this